# How can I check whether a nonlinear system is zero-state observable?

Tags: control-engineering, control-theory

Given a nonlinear system, such as:

$$\begin{align}
x_1' &= x_2 \\
x_2' &= −x_1^3 + u \\
y    &= x_2
\end{align}$$

How can I check the **zero-state observability** of the system?

Comment: I've never heard that term (probably because I am not a controls engineer) but what is zero-state observability?

Comment: @starrise>
The system
`x' = f(x, u)`

`y = h(x, u)`
with `f(0, 0) = h(0, 0) = 0` is said to be **zero-state observable**
if no solution of `x' = f(x, 0)` can stay identically in
`S = {x ∈ Rn | h(x, 0) = 0}`, other than `x(t) = 0`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've found the answer.

To check if a system is **zero state observable**, put $u=0$ and check whether $x=0$ when $y=0$. If yes, it is **zero-state observable**. Otherwise not!

For the given system, by putting $u=0$ and $y=0$, we see that $x_2=0$, therefore $x'_2=0$ and thus $-x_1^3=0$ or $x_1=0 \implies x=0$. Thus it is **zero-state observable**.

Comment: What is the difference to zero-state detectably?